# Get Network Type in Android without the need to ask for permisson

Tags: java, android

I need to get the connection type of the user **without** asking for permission. (Internal App)

Currently I'm using this:

```
public static String getNetworkType() {

        int networkType = Application.getPhoneManager().getNetworkType();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN:
                return "Wlan";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "2g / GPRS";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "3g";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "LTE";
            default:
                return "Notfound";
        }
    }
```

But this does not detect if the user is on wifi. If the user is on wifi, it then returns LTE. If the user switches off wifi and checks into 3g network, it works.

Could anybody explain how to check if a user is on wifi without asking for permission to do so?